# how to detect signals from cells within a QTableWidget that contain spinboxes or comboboxes?

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qtablewidget, qdoublespinbox

I have a QTableWidget that is made up of two columns: Diameters and Areas

I inserted QDoubleSpinBoxes into every cell. When I enter data into one, I want to be able to detect that and automatically generate the area using the value I inserted in the corresponding cell.

So how exactly do I send a signal when I changed the value of a diameter at a certain row, to the function to calculate the area using that diameter and then update the cell right next to it in the Area column on the same row with that value calculated?

```
 QObject::connect(TabUI.tableWidget,SIGNAL(cellChanged()), this, SLOT(CalculateArea()));
```

---

```
    void Pressurator::CalculateArea()
{

//        QTableWidgetItem * item = new QTableWidgetItem;
//        double area = 0;
//        QDoubleSpinBox * diameter_SB =  static_cast<QDoubleSpinBox*>(TabUI.tableWidget->cellWidget(item->row(),0));
//        QDoubleSpinBox * area_SB =  static_cast<QDoubleSpinBox*>(TabUI.tableWidget->cellWidget(item->row(),1));

//        area = M_PI * qPow(diameter_SB->value()/2, 2);
//        area_SB->setValue(area);
    qDebug()<<"DETECTED";
}
```

This is where the QTableWidget is generated:

```
 void Pressurator::NozzleCount()
{
 int nozzleCount = TabUI.nozzlesNum_SB->value();
// QDoubleSpinBox * nozzleD_A_SB = new QDoubleSpinBox;
// nozzleD_A_SB->setRange(0,10000);
 TabUI.tableWidget->setColumnCount(3);
 TabUI.tableWidget->setRowCount(nozzleCount);

QStringList labels = {"Diameter","Area","Type"};
 TabUI.tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(labels);

// QHeaderView* header = TabUI.tableWidget->horizontalHeader();
// header->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);

 for(int i=0 ; i< nozzleCount; i++)
 {

 QDoubleSpinBox * ND_SB = new QDoubleSpinBox;
 QDoubleSpinBox * NA_SB = new QDoubleSpinBox;
 QComboBox * nozzleType = new QComboBox;

 ND_SB->setDecimals(5);ND_SB->setRange(0,500);
 NA_SB->setDecimals(5);NA_SB->setRange(0,500);
 nozzleType->addItems(nozzleTypesList);


 TabUI.tableWidget->setCellWidget(i,0, ND_SB);
 TabUI.tableWidget->setCellWidget(i,1, NA_SB);
 TabUI.tableWidget->setCellWidget(i,2, nozzleType);
 }

}
```

Comment: How did you add the spin box widgets to the table? Using `QTableWidget::setCellWidget()`?

Comment: yes I added them in another function which basically acquires a number from the user which is basically the row number, and inside a for loop the spin widgets are added

Comment: Please add this part of code to the question too. It might be important for writing the answer.

Comment: I made the edit

Answer (score 0):

If you call `setCellWidget`, you won't get `cellChanged` signal from QTableWidget. You have to connect the QDoubleSpinBoxes's `valueChanged` signal. If you have bigger and dynamic table using ItemDelegates will better.

Also Qt has an [example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-spinboxdelegate-example.html) for QSpinBox delegate and it has a disadvantage if you use the code out of the box. The disadvantage is If you change the spinbox's value, the QTableWidget's `cellChanged` signal won't emit until press enter or click other cell.

If you want emit signal immediately you have to add this connection into `createEditor` function before return statement:

```cpp
connect(editor, QOverload<decltype(editor->value())>::of(&QSpinBox::valueChanged), [=](auto val){
        auto ptr = const_cast<SpinBoxDelegate*>(this);
       emit ptr->commitData(editor);
    });
```